# How do I change the language of the man pages on Debian, while keeping the default language as english

Tags: debian, man, locale, language

I've tried changing the man pages on debian from English to Italian but all I have tried hasn't worked yet.

First of all, I installed the manpages in Italian with `apt install manpages-it`.

I then edited the `/etc/locale.gen` file and uncommented it_IT.utf8, then ran `locale-gen` to update it. After that I tried with:

```bash
man -Lit printf
man --locale=it printf
LANG=it_IT.utf8
```

but none give me the manual pages in Italian.

The only manual page in Italian I can get is `man man`, but the other manuals are just in English.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there's simply not many translated manual pages; when you look at the output of `dpkg -L manpages-it`, which lists all the files in the `manpages-it` package, you'll see it's only 107 pages – `man` is one of them, `bash` is another one. And then there's 71 other Italian pages that are part of other packages – anyways, not even close to maybe 500 English pages that come with a barebone debian installation.

So, long story short: I'm afraid `man` can't show you Italian pages that don't exist. It *should* care about the `LANG` environment variable being set *before* you call man:

```bash
export LANG=it_IT.utf8
man bash # should open the Italian bash page
man mkfs # should open the English mkfs page, since no Italian page exists
```

But in my experience that's extremely rarely actually working :-/. I'm not sure fixing that is worth the effort.

Comment: thank you very much for the help!